# Subscribe on property in loop - KnockoutJs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable, subscribe

I need help in subsribing on property in object. I don't know which property name will be and how much, I'm generating an object of properties according to data from the server.

I have code like:

```
viVm.requestData.ageGroups = {};

    var classificators = viVm.requestData.multiTrip() === 1
        ? viVm.classificators.ageGroups.multiTrip
        : viVm.classificators.ageGroups.singleTrip;

    classificators().forEach(function (entry, index) {
        var entry = ko.toJS(entry);
        var code = entry.code;

        viVm.requestData.ageGroups[code] = 0;

        viVm.requestData.ageGroups[code].subscribe(function (newValue) {
            validateAgeGroupValue(newValue, viVm.requestData.ageGroups[code]);
        });

    });
```

It sets up property and it's value tom0, but on `.subscribe()` step I get an error - `viVm.requestData.ageGroups[code].subscribe is not a function`

Could enybody explain what I do wrong and maybe offer some variant how to make it work?
Thank you.

Comment: Two questions, 1. are you sure your ternary operator is accurate? You are saying if it is ===1 then its a multi-trip, whereas if it is not it is a single trip? Shouldn't it be the other way around. 2. Have you tried subscribing to the actual property ageGroup. Assuming you are receiving an observable that you can subscribe to. Try that.

Comment: Also in your function you are setting viVm.requestData.ageGroups[code] = 0; and then saying 0.subscribe? that won't work

Comment: 1) yes, it's correct. 2)I have no property ageGroup, only ageGroups with properties inside. In the beginnig I do init of empty object where add properties thought loop, so . ageGroups[code] = 0 is property: 0. I thought it should make property.subscribe.

Comment: yes sorry meant ageGroups not group. But that still won't work here what you are doing is setting viVm.requestData.ageGroups[code] to 0. So you are subscribing to 0.subscribe. What I think you are trying to do is get the value of viVm.requestData.ageGroups at position 0. Is that not correct?

Comment: Also as I suspected once you use ko.toJS the data is no longer presented as an observable. (ko.toJS — this clones your view model’s object graph, substituting for each observable the current value of that observable, so you get a plain copy that contains only your data and no Knockout-related artifacts) Would you mind posting sample data so I may test out a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because 0 (zero) is not a Knockout observable (function). You are trying to subscribe to an integer.

Try this:

```
        viVm.requestData.ageGroups[code] = ko.observable(0);

        viVm.requestData.ageGroups[code].subscribe(function (newValue) {
            validateAgeGroupValue(newValue, viVm.requestData.ageGroups[code]);
        });
```

Comment: Nice! What I was trying to explain but much better ^^